# C: is pthread_self() and pthread_t variable one and the same?

Tags: c, pthreads

This is what I am wondering:

**If I create a thread with pthread_create() and then call pthread_self() from that thread, will that value match the pthread_t value that I pass to pthread_create in the main thread?**

```
//pthread_t variable
pthread_t producer_thread = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));;

//create the thread
pthread_create(producer_thread, NULL, producer, NULL);

printf("Pthread_t variable after creating thread says %d\n", producer_thread);

....

//function passed to thread
void producer(void *p){
  printf("Pthread self says: %d\n", pthread_self());
}
```

Comment: What, you're calling the same function twice subsequently, and getting different results?..

Comment: You should be getting one value repeated, and the two values should be smushed up against each other since you don't force a space between the two values, because you are printing `pthread_self()` twice.  What is 'all the initialization' doing?

Comment: Your `mythreadId` have uninitialised value. Assign it first.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: post valid code that reproduces your problem (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And very sorry, but asking question with wrong code and then using uppercase-attitude comments looks so very wrong.

Comment: keltar, you did not correct me at all but were very judgemental. It was obviously a typo.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov that was correct (compilable). How would anyone beside you know what you're doing? I've asked for confirmation, because it _seemed_ to be wrong. Anyway, how many times you've already edited question, turning it all around (edited comments changes _a_ _lot_)? And it still completely vague _what_ value you've assigned to `mythreadId`, if you did (unspecified too). Just make _complete_ example as was already asked.

Comment: I would say that `producer_thread` is not a pointer type, and you using it as pointer in `pthread_create` and as value in `printf`. But it will end up with 'typo' conversation again :-(. Anyway, correct version of your code works flawlessly for me (except adding some delay after thread finish and using `%ld` instead of `%d`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type of pthread_self is pthread_t which is basically a pointer not of integer type.

So, it is printing its address(typecasted to int), not `pthread_t` structure.

You can use `pthread_equal` function to check if these pthread_t are same or not. Means, in another thread, use

```
 printf("%d\n", pthread_equal(mythreadId, pthread_self()));
```

It should print a non-zero number indicating that they correspond to the same thread.

If they are not same, then it is a problem.

Print `mythreadId` in the thread what is spawns. It must match with main's pthread_t. If they are different, then there is a problem.